# Density of set of unique sums

Tags: nt.number-theory

Set $U_1 = \{1,2\}$, and for $n\in\mathbb{N}$ with $n\geq 1$ we set $U_{n+1} = U_n\cup A_n$ where $A_n$ is the set of elements of $\mathbb{N}$ that are not in $U_n$ but can be uniquely written as a sum of $2$ elements of $U_n$.

Set $U=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} U_n$.

What is the value of $$\lim \inf_{n\to\infty}\frac{|U\cap\{1,\ldots,n\}|}{n}$$?

**EDIT**: The sequence $\frac{|U\cap \{1,\ldots, n\}|}{n}$ seems to have a trend to grow smaller  as $n$ grows large; I conjecture that the value I look for might be zero.

Comment: Is there some conjecture about the value? Did you try some experiments  (by hand or using the computer) to calculate $|U_n|$ at least for some small $n$'s? (The next logical step would be checking whether that sequence appears in OEIS.)

Comment: Thanks Martin for your comment; I conjecture the value is $0$ -- I edited the post accordingly.

Comment: Just to check whether I understood the problem correctly, are these first values correct?
$U_1=\{1,2\}$, $U_2=\{3,4\}$, $U_3=\{6,7,8\}$, $U_4=\{12,13,15,16\}$, $U_5=\{24,25,26,27,29,30,31,32\}$, $U_6=\{48,49,63,64\}$

Comment: It turns out (see [Emil Jeřábek's comment](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/240196/density-of-set-of-unique-sums/240255#comment594120_240255)) that what I posted is not an answer to your question.

Comment: If you read the comments to my answer, you can see that writing out the set $U_n$ at least for a few small $n$'s could help to clarify your question. (Specifically Emil Jeřábek asked whether when you write "sum of two elements", these two elements are supposed to be distinct. In other words, whether $4=2+2$ belongs to $A_2$ or not.)

Comment: Several issues worth being mentioned: a) appearance of $13$ in $A_5$, although $\max U_4=16>13$ ($13$ is not representable by $U_3$), as well as of $51$ in $A_7$; b) NOT appearance of $25$ in $U_6$ (it was not representable by $U_4$, but it is multiply representable by $U_5$); and c) NOT appearance of $49$ in $U+U$.(no numbers below $49$ can appear in $A_n$ with $n\geq 7$). This may warn from too simple approaches.

Comment: @IlyaBogdanov I think that $28\notin A_5$, since $28=14+14=12+16$. Otherwise I got the same sets $A_2$ to $A_5$. I did not try $A_6$.

Comment: @MartinSleziak: Oh, sorry! 28 also wasn't in my $A_5$. it was just a typo. So hopefully $A_6$ is still correct.

Comment: _After a correction_: If my computations are (now) correct, we have $A_2=\{3,4\}$, $A_3=\{7,8\}$, $A_4=\{12,14,15,16\}$, $A_5=\{13,21,26,27,29,31,32\}$, $A_6=\{50,54,55,56,57,59,60,61,62,63,64\}$.